# Issue in Starting Integrated Weblogic sever in JDeveloper 12.2.2.1.0

Tags: oracle, soa, jdeveloper

Facing issue as mentioned in the error screen while starting Weblogic server. I am unable to start the server.

Windows 7 32 bit, 8gb ram
JDK 1.8.0
JRE 1.8.0

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwQRj.jpg)

Comment: The message seems pretty self-explanatory? This is off-topic anyway. And also [please post text not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the memory properties of the WebLogic? Seems they are not the default.
Are you running out of space on your machine's hard-drive for temporary files?